# Json array appending a object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

i have pushed data to an array like this

```
this.data.push{'data': 'type',
  'value': 'apple'}
```

and i want to append the value of that particular array's value object. I tried to do it like this

```
this.data[index].value.push = 'banana';
```

but it doesn't work?? I want to replace the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding items to arrays work like this in javascript:

```
this.data.push({'data': 'type', 'value': 'apple'});
```

However, given that your data is an object, you don't need to use push:

```
this.data[index].value = 'banana';
```

You can access a value from a javascript object directly.

Given that you have used string keys, you will probably have to do the following:

```
this.data[index]['value'] = 'banana';
```

Look at this for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: I tried it. It's not working. it's giving `Cannot set property 'value' of undefined` this error

Comment: So the problem is that this.data is not getting the correct thing. You should do console.log(this.data); and tell me what you see.

Comment: Ok so what that either means is that this.data is not defined or you're putting an index that is out of range of the array. You'll either need to use this.data[0] or look at how this.data is defined. I suggest you make a new variable like so: var data = {'data': 'type', 'value': 'apple'}; then try doing what everyone has suggested on this new variable instead.

Answer (score 4):

`Push` is a function `Array.push()`

```
this.data[index].push('banana');
```

Comment: I want to replace only the value object of that particular index not all the data

Comment: Than you should do this this way: 

this.data[index].value = "your new value"

Answer (score 2):

> i have pushed data to an array like this
>
> ```
> this.data.push{'data': 'type', 'value': 'apple'}
> ```

No! That does not work without getting a syntax error.

You could use

```
this.data.push({'data': 'type', 'value': 'apple'});
```

for inserting a new object at the end of the array `data`.

For changing a specific objects's property, you need to assign the new content, like

```
this.data[index].value = 'banana';
```

This takes an element and the property and assigns the new value `'banana'` to it.

Please have a look to [properties accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) for objects, like

> ```
> object.property
> object["property"]
> ```

Answer (score 1):

push takes a parameter of object, you must have pass this parameter in braces

```
this.data.push({'data': 'type',  'value': 'apple'})
```

to change value you can directly change field value

```
this.data[index].value = 'banana';
```

if you want to keep multiple values in `value` then make value an `array` as well.

Comment: you want extra field to insert or want to change the value?

Answer (score 1):

make it

```
this.data[index].value = ['banana'];
```

since you need to replace the value of `value` attribute with an array.

If this needs to be repeated again then

```
Array.isArray(this.data[index].value) ? (this.data[index].value = ['banana']) : this.data[index].value.push('banana');
```